# How to send message to signalR specific PersistentConnection by its ID ? (with asp.net mvc4 web-api)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I use class `Echo` derived from `PersistentConnection`, and I want to send a message to certain connection:

```
var client = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetConnectionContext<Echo>();
client.Connection.Broadcast(msg);
```

But I want to send it to specific connection ID. Do I have to create a group for every connection or start using Hubs, or there is a simpler way to select connection by ID, something like:

```
GetConnectionById(id).Send(msg);
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Message can be sent to a specific connection ID, but the syntax is not same as what you specified in the question. Following snippet shows the syntax:

```
return Connection.Send(connectionId, Message);
```

Source of my answer: [SignalR wiki on Github](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/PersistentConnection)

I think, you are aware that SignalR 1 Alpha is released. It is possible to send message to a specific client by its ID if you use this version. Following snippet shows it:

```
var connection = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetConnectionContext<Echo>().Connection;
connection.Send(((Connection)connection).Identity, "Message to be sent");
```

Here, `((Connection)connection).Identity` gives connection ID of the requesting client.

Comment: But that only possible from within the `Echo` class (that inherits `PersistentConnection`). How do I do that from outside (without `Dictionary`s and additional complication of data management overhead) ?

Comment: It's the same API, you call connection.Send passing the id.